# Selecting Proper Range in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am copying data from one workbook to another. I am continuously struggling with Range and cannot figure out as how should I insert data as I want.

```
            Workbook A                                 Workbook B
         ID           Name                         Id            Name
         1A                                        3C            Sarah
         2A                                        4J            Joy
         5D                                        R8            Lucas
```

Result

```
             (Expected)                                Reality
         ID           Name                         Id            Name
         1A                                        1A            Sarah
         2A                                        2A            Joy
         5D                                        5D            Lucas
         3C           Sarah                        3C
         4J           Joy                          4J
         R8           Lucas                        R8


  Sub CopyOttiCoverage()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim NextRow As Long

Set x = Workbooks.Open("H\A.xlsm")
Set y = ThisWorkbook 'Workbooks.Open("H:\B.xlsx")

x.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("A65536").Select
ActiveCell.End(xlUp).Select
LastRow = ActiveCell.Row
Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Copy y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Copy y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("b65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

As shown above when I copy records from B to A, where A has all blanks in Name field, the result puts Names in wrong places. So I think that it has something to do with the range that I paste. Also if someone can tell me if its possible to insert a date column before ID column and update it with system date. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't the ID for Joy 4J?  Why is the expected ID 1A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the bottom paste line to:

```
Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Copy y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1)
```

and put it above the other line.  So it will look like this:

```
Sub CopyOttiCoverage()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim NextRow As Long

Set x = Workbooks.Open("H\A.xlsm")
Set y = ThisWorkbook 'Workbooks.Open("H:\B.xlsx")

x.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("A65536").Select
ActiveCell.End(xlUp).Select
LastRow = ActiveCell.Row
Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Copy y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1)
Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Copy y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

This probably isn't the best way to do this, but it should work.

EDIT:  Also, you could copy the whole range at once by doing this:

```
Range("A2:B" & LastRow).Copy y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)
```

Then if you change the "B" to "C, D, X" whatever, you can get a whole bunch of connected columns.

Comment: Thanks. Just a small question, what do i do if this is the case for 5th column, I mean the same thing is to be done in 5th or some other column? How to change the offset. Thanks'

Comment: If you need to copy other columns, then you can change the offset to "offset(1,x)" where x is the column you wish to offset.